# Autocomplete textbox winforms

Tags: winforms, autocomplete

I would like to know if is there any way to create some dynamically autocomplete for textbox with dynamic data from database?

Something like jQuery/ajax in ASP.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create `AutoCompleteStringCollection` add own suggestions using Array. Set this collection to your textBox as `AutoCompleteCustomSource`. Use this sample. Also you can use `TextChanged` event and get your collections from Db with params like text.StartWith("textBoxValue").

> Use the AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and AutoCompleteSource properties to create a TextBox that automatically completes input strings by comparing the prefix being entered to the prefixes of all strings in a maintained source.This is useful for TextBox controls in which URLs, addresses, file names, or commands will be frequently entered.

Here msdn  [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection autoCollection= new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCollection;
           txtBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
           txtBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }

 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text.Lenght > 2)
        {

              autoCollection = yourCollectionFromDB(textBox1.Text)
              txtBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCollection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, but in this case I have to load all data in the start of my program and fill the array. But I mean load results to suggest dynamicaly. For example: the user start typeing and I select only 10 top rows from database. Is it possible?